# Throw Exception in Function apply for CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm having some tasks created like follows (this is just for demonstration normally network calls):

```
public class RandomTask implements Function<String, String> {
    private int number;
    private int waitTime;
    private boolean throwError;

    public RandomTask(int number, int waitTime, boolean throwError) {
        this.number = number;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.throwError = throwError;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        System.out.println("Job " + number + " started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);

            if (throwError) {
                throw new InterruptedException("Something happened");
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return "RandomTask " + number + " finished";
    }
}
```

Then I have a Chain class where I chain some tasks together per job.

```
static CompletableFuture<String> start(ExecutorService executorService) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Foo", executorService)
            .thenApplyAsync(new RandomTask(3, 100, false), executorService)
            .thenApplyAsync(new RandomTask(4, 100, false), executorService);

    return future2;
}
```

I then start 2 chains as follows:

```
  CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(Chain1.start(fixedThreadPool), Chain2.start(fixedThreadPool));
    try {
        combinedFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That way the two chains start off at the same time.

Now I want to throw an exception in a task and catch it where I call combinedFuture.get() so that I know which task has failed in my chain.

The thing is dat I can't adapt the Function because CompletableFutures complains about this. I tried with:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is this not possible or how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

“That way the two chains start off at the same time.” indicates that you have a fundamentally wrong understanding of how `CompletableFuture` works.

Asynchronous operations are submitted to the executor service right when you create them or as soon as their prerequisites are available. So in case of `supplyAsync`, which has no dependencies, the asynchronous operation starts right within the `supplyAsync` invocation.

All, a construct like `CompletableFuture.allOf(job1, job2).get()` does, is to create a new stage depending on both jobs and waiting for its completion, so the net result is just to wait for the completion of both jobs. It does *not* start the jobs. They are already running. Waiting for a completion has no influence of the process of completing.

Chaining a `CompletableFuture` with a custom function type allowing checked exceptions can be done as

```
public static <T,R> CompletableFuture<R> thenApplyAsync(
    CompletableFuture<T> f, CheckedFunction<? super T, ? extends R> cf,
    Executor e) {

    CompletableFuture<R> r = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.whenCompleteAsync((v,t) -> {
        try {
            if(t != null) r.completeExceptionally(t);
            else r.complete(cf.apply(v));
        } catch(Throwable t2) {
            r.completeExceptionally(t2);
        }
    }, e);
    return r;
}
```

To use this method, instead of chaining calls on the `CompletableFuture`, you have to nest them. E.g.

```
static CompletableFuture<String> start(ExecutorService executorService) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future2 = 
        thenApplyAsync(thenApplyAsync(
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Foo", executorService),
            new RandomTask(3, 100, false), executorService),
            new RandomTask(4, 100, false), executorService);

    return future2;
}
```

given

```
public class RandomTask implements CheckedFunction<String, String> {
    private int number, waitTime;
    private boolean throwError;

    public RandomTask(int number, int waitTime, boolean throwError) {
        this.number = number;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
        this.throwError = throwError;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(String s) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Job " + number + " started");
        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        if (throwError) {
            throw new InterruptedException("Something happened in "+number);
        }
        return "RandomTask " + number + " finished";
    }
}
```

You can still create two tasks and wait for both like

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(Chain1.start(fixedThreadPool), Chain2.start(fixedThreadPool))
    .join();
```